# Is it possible to use jQueryFormWizard with UI Tabs? or any other solution for wizard with tabs and validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a form wizard and trying to achieve tabs for steps and multi-part validation on each step. Some one suggested me to use [jQuery Form Wizard](http://thecodemine.org/). Can any one guide me how to achieve both wizard with steps along with validation on each step using jQuery.

Comment: what exactly is the problem you are facing? I am using [this](http://techlaboratory.net/products.php?product=smartwizard) plugin for the same requirement and its working great

Comment: What does this plugin have for validation?

Comment: it does validation on each step of your form using jQuery, chek the validation demo in that link. Anyway you didn't mention what problem are you facing with validation

Comment: I just cant figure out how to use validation with it. It looks like in this code he is using custom validation for each field, I have lot of fields in wizard and wondering how to use above script. I do not have expert knowledge about jQuery you can consider me a beginner... can you show me your code ... or some explanation on how to use it?

Comment: Ok i looked into that library and it looks like they are using aa additional plugin for validation. Why dont you try using the plugin i suggested. If you look at the siurce of [this](http://techlaboratory.net/labs/SmartWizard2/smartwizard2-validation.php) page you can find functions  validateStep1(), validateStep1() etc. If you couldn't understand the validation codes in these functions then tell me i will try to write the validation codes for your form

Comment: Anu Please read my last comment on Answer by aleafonso

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4905/discussion-between-anu-and-imran)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Smart Wizard](http://techlaboratory.net/labs/SmartWizard2/smartwizard2-validation.php) with step validation. I've been using it for a while and it looks pretty flexible.

Hope this helps!

Comment: in Smart Wizard validation looks a bit confusing to me. Can you please refer me to some guide for its usage. Can you show me where did you use it just as an reference please?

Comment: I find out in their [documentation](http://techlaboratory.net/products.php?product=smartwizard&action=2) : 

"Smart Wizard 2.0 does not have in-built form validation, but you can call you own validation function for each steps..."

Can we use jQuery Validation Plugin with it. If yes... please guide how? Thanks in advance

Comment: As you can see, the validation is done using javascript. If you know javascript, you'd be able to do something according to your validation needs. Otherwise, it would require a higher amount of time and effort to get to a solution. Good luck with that.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. But I do not have much knowledge of javascript. That is why I am trying to do it with some validation plugin. I found [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) but cant figure out how to use it with the plugin you suggested or with jQuery UI Tabs